# Write image to clipboard in Firefox

Tags: firefox, clipboard

I'm currently trying to write an image blob data to the clipboard in Firefox (104.0 Linux).

I seeked information about Permissions, and Clipboard.
As for the permissions, I found contradictory things, some that say you should request for some clipboard write permission (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard), some that say that the permission is temporary granted on user interaction. The later seems to work because I'm able to use navigator.clipboard.writeText("blah") to write successfuly  to the clipboard.

Problem is when trying to write data. Mozilla documentation states about 2 versions :

- Clipboard.write() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write)
  Seems obsolete or something, because the method simply doesn't exist, I only have writeText()
- setImageData() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/clipboard/setImageData). This one makes absolutely no sense as browser doesn't exist, as well as setImageData() in the navigator.clipboard instance

Any help would be grealty appreciated here !

EDIT : in fact to actually gt a definition for write() method, user has to manually define a bool true value for flag dom.events.asyncClipboard.clipboardItem in about:config
So, pretty much unusable in production environment, if you don't expect power users only...

So now, I have a new issue, even with that bool set to true, firefox goes "lack of user activation" half of the time, even though the tab is focused. It seems I have to actually *do* something on the page in order to get it to work ; IE. move the mouse, click here and there...
I even tried to add a prompt, as my clipboard.write() occurs deep in await/async stuff under the button click handle (I'm actually in a NodeJS/Nuxt environment), and writing to the clipboard from the prompt, and even there, I get that error...

Comment: OK, I progressed on this, in fact, since Firefox 87 or so, to have actually the write() method defined, the user has to define a custom configuration bool as true : dom.events.asyncClipboard.clipboardItem.